# Centering all of the points in iOS OpenGL ES app

Tags: ios, matrix, opengl-es, shader

I have an OpenGL view that displays a set of 3D points with some basic shaders:

```
// Fragment Shader

static const char* PointFS = STRINGIFY
(

 void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0);
}

);

// Vertex Shader

static const char* PointVS = STRINGIFY
(
 uniform mediump mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

 attribute mediump vec4 position;

 void main( void )
{
    gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * position;
    gl_PointSize = 3.0;
}

);
```

And the MVP matrix is calculated as:

```
- (void)setMatrices
{
    // ModelView Matrix
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(modelViewMatrix, 2, 2, 2);

    // Projection Matrix
    const GLfloat aspectRatio = (GLfloat)(self.view.bounds.size.width) / (GLfloat)(self.view.bounds.size.height);
    const GLfloat fieldView = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90.0f);
    const GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(fieldView, aspectRatio, 0.1f, 10.0f);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(self.pointShader.uProjectionMatrix, 1, 0, GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix).m);
}
```

This works fine, but **I have a set of 500 points and I see only a few**.

How do I scale/translate the MVP matrix to display all of them (they are a dynamic set)? Ideally the "centroid" should be at the origin, and all of the points visible. It should be able to adapt to rotations of the view (gestures are the next step I want to implement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing how you present this you might need quite a lot... I guess best approach might be using "look at", the point you are looking at is `(0,0,0)` as you stated, camera position should probably be `(0,0,Z)` and up `(0,1,0)`. So the only issue here is the Z component of camera position.

If you start the Z with for instance `-.1` and the iterate through all the points then `sin(fieldView*.5f) * (p.z-Z) >= point.y` for the point to be visible. So you can compute `Z1 = p.z-(point.y/sin(fieldView*.5f))` and if `Z1<Z` then `Z=Z1`. This check is only for the positive Y check, you also need the same for negative Y and same for +-X. These evasions are very similar though when checking X you could also take the screen ratio into account.

This procedure should give you the smallest field possible to see all the points (with given limitations such as looking towards (0,0,0)) but is far from the simplest. You also need to consider if the equation will work if `p.z<-Z`.

Another bit easier approach is to generate the smallest cube around centre which holds all the points: iterate through points and get the coordinate with largest absolute value (any of X,Y or Z). When you have it use it with frustum instead perspective so that all rect parameters (top, bottom, left and right) are generated with this value as `+-largest`. Then you need to compute the translation which for 90 degrees field is `Z = (largest*.5)`. Z is the zNear for the frustum and then also translate the matrix by  `-(Z+largest)`. Again one of the coordinate in frustum must be multiplied by screen ratio.

In any case do watch out what your `zFar` is, having it only 10.0f might be a bit too short in your case. Until you need the depth buffer you should not worry about that value being too large.

Comment: Wow, that's a great answer. I'll take some time to go over it and test it, then I'll come back. Thanks

Comment: OK, I still didn't get it working yet, but I somehow think that z values are outside of the frustum, that's why I cannot see them. By translating them -(zFar/2) I can see something.

Comment: Maybe the translation has a wrong sign (you are looking at the wrong way) try a negative value. Or if you are using "look at" do the same for position vector.

Comment: OK, big whoops moment here, was passing always 4 to the `glDrawArrays` method, that's why it wasn't showing all of the points O_o - that said the model seems to be always centered with the frustum way, but the points are "flickering" in the screen, is this related to the view?

Comment: The flickering should not be related. Try logging the uniforms and attributes before the draw call and check if there are differences between 2 sequential frames. Also some potentials are in blend settings, colour settings...

Comment: Thanks, accepted the answer as it solves my original problem. I will debug as you suggested for the flickering.